# How to set up a basic home network file sharing?

Tags: networking

I have 3  machines, all on Ubuntu 10.10,
2 desktops wired to a router, and one Laptop via wifi.

I am using Ubuntu for 3 years now, but not yet feeling comfortable using the terminal.

How do I set up a basic home network (graphically?) so I can access files from all machines, without been depended on the Internet (Like Ubuntu One)

*(Internet connection in my area is not stable)

I had enough copy-paste files using a jump-drive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would create a Shared folder on one of the desktops (the one with the most free hard drive space). Then you can access that Shared folder from other computers.
To Share a folder right click on the folder and choose Sharing or if you don't see that choose properties and then choose sharing.
If you don't have Samba installed, you should be asked to install Samba. 
You can allow access to specific users or you can make the folder available to anyone on the network (probably easiest on a small home network).

Then from the other computers navigate to the Network (on the list of Places) and find the computer with the Shared folder. Open the folder and then make a bookmark. Anything you place in that folder from one computer will be accessible from all the other computers.

Sorry I can't give you exact step by steps as I don't have a 10.10 machine in front of me.

Answer (score 7):

You can right click on a folder and choose "Sharing Options"

[image]

then select "Share this folder"

[image]

Comment: What icon theme are you using?

Comment: This is Faience from this ppa: https://launchpad.net/~tiheum/+archive/equinox/ Enjoy ;-)